# Send SMS using Nextel API with sender number visible Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, vonage

I am using Vonage API for sending SMS through Node JS application. The receiver receives the message but from an anonymous number. Is there a way to show some text in From field so that the receiver will recognise the sender ? I am using Indian numbers for sending and receiving messages.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a [sender identity](https://developer.nexmo.com/messaging/sms/guides/custom-sender-id).

For instance in the code below the variable `from` is that name which will be shown to have sent the message, visible on the receiver's phone.

```js
const from = THE_SENDER_IDENTITY
const to = TO_NUMBER
const text = 'A text message sent using the Vonage SMS API'

vonage.message.sendSms(from, to, text, (err, responseData) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        if(responseData.messages[0].status === "0") {
            console.log("Message sent successfully.");
        } else {
            console.log(`Message failed with error: ${responseData.messages[0]['error-text']}`);
        }
    }
})
```